# No water flow in the radiator - 99 Cadillac STS

Tags: engine, cooling-system, overheating, cadillac

What's wrong when water doesn't flow from your radiator. I already put a water pump and a thermostat on putits still running hot. What could be the problem?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the engine is running hot, e.g Dash temp gauge, Electric Fans switching on, OBD2 parameters, boiling coolant, tested coolant temperature?

Comment: Do your cooling fans kick on? Does the heater work? Does the radiator feel warm when the engine is hot? Did you remember to have the heater on when you re-filled the radiator? How the did coolant look when you drained it?

Answer (score 2):

If there is no/insufficient coolant flow in the cooling system then there are a few options:

- There is insufficient coolant in the system (check the coolant level);
- It's flowing out of the system (probably on the ground);
- The thermostat is stuck closed (it's defective and needs replacement);
- The water pump is not doing it's job (it's defective or not connected to a belt);
- A part of the cooling system is clogged (radiator or piping);
- There is air in the cooling system (cause of improper air purging after refilling drained coolant) - thanks to **Tim B** for reminding about this one.

Comment: I think you've covered all bases, though I'm not sure if coolant flow would be completely stopped by a stuck-closed thermostat.

Comment: @Zaid we talked about that aready, I believe. Coolant flow would be limited to the small circle only, mostly inside the engine. I still believe that no coolant should be able to get through to the radiator at all in the case of a closed thermostat.

Comment: Another possibility is that the cooling system was not sufficiently purged of air after the water pump and thermostat were replaced.

Comment: @Tim B you're right, totally forgot that one